# How to do an UNPIVOT on this json data?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I commonly have json data that is stored in BigQuery that is a key-value mapping such as the following:

```
id      product      sales_data
1       socks        {"US": {"Price": 2.99, "Currency": "USD"},
                      "CA": {"Price": 3.04, "Currency": "CAD"}}
```

What I want to do is two-fold:

- First, push the 'keys' into a consistent values struct
- Unnest the now-consistent data

For example:

```
# push_keys_to_value(field,      path, renamed)
# push_keys_to_value(sales_data, '$',  'Country'}

id      product      sales_data
1       socks        [{"Price" 2.99, "Currency": "USD", "Country": "US"}, {"Price" 3.04, "Currency": "CAD", "Country": "CA"}]
```

Now unnested:

```
id      product      sales_data
1       socks        {"Price" 2.99, "Currency": "USD", "Country": "US"}
1       socks        {"Price" 3.04, "Currency": "CAD", "Country": "CA"}
```

This is a pretty common pattern I have -- taking string (json) data and 'un-pivoting' it. How could I do this in BigQuery, and is this a common pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select id, product, country,
  json_extract_scalar(_, '$.Price') Price,
  json_extract_scalar(_, '$.Currency') Currency
from (
  select *, regexp_extract(sales_date, r'"' || country || '": ({.*?})') _
  from your_table, 
  unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys`(sales_date)) country
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: thanks, could you please explain these two lines: `unnest(bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys(sales_date))` and `regexp_extract(sales_date, r'"' || country || '": ({.*?})')` ?

Comment: `bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys` is very simple udf (available in public project and just a simple wrapper around `return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));`) that extracts keys from json - so in your case - it extracts "US" and "CA". and then `regexp_extract` - extracts respective country's json value which yet then is parsed for Price and Currency values

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's a generic way to do this? I.e., without knowing the keys of the values object?

Comment: i don't think so! it is just matter of different workarounds - out of which  the one in my answer sounds the best for me - but obviously this can be matter of preferences :o)